# Remove a Function from being repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Its hard to explain this so I'll try my best.

Is it possible to use .remove() to remove a javascript function from being repeated?

**function**

```
function readytouseCard() {
    console.log(this);
    $('.cardCVV input[name=cvv1]').keyup(function () {
        console.log("s");
        var checkCVV = $('.cardCVV input[name=cvv1]').filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length < 3;
        }).length === 0;
        if (checkCVV) {
            $("li.checkCode").addClass("checked");
        } else {
            $("li.checkCode").removeClass("checked");
        }
        checklistCheck();
    });

    function checklistCheck() {
        var counting = $("li.checked:not(.title)").length;
        if (counting == 6) {
            console.log(counting);
            $("input[name=purchase]").attr("disabled", false);
            $("input[name=purchase]").removeClass("purchase-btn-disabled");
            $("input[name=purchase]").addClass("purchase-btn");

        } else {
            $("input[name=purchase]").attr("disabled", true);
            $("input[name=purchase]").removeClass("purchase-btn");
            $("input[name=purchase]").addClass("purchase-btn-disabled");
        }
    }
}
```

**The Main**

```
$("li#usercurrentcc").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var qString = 'selectedID=' + selectedID;
    $.post('/assets/inc/get-logged-info-card.php', qString, function (results) {
        if ($("#usercurrentccbox, #addnewccbox").length != 0) {
            $("#usercurrentccbox, #addnewccbox").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $(this).remove();
                $("<div class='creditCardDetails' id='usercurrentccbox'><div class='creditCard'><div class='cardChoice'><span>Choose Card Type</span><input name='cctype1' type='radio' value='V' class='lft-field' id='visa' /><label for='visa'></label><input name='cctype1' type='radio' value='M' class='lft-field' id='mastercard' /><label for='mastercard'></label><input name='cctype1' type='radio' value='A' class='lft-field' id='amex' /><label for='amex'></label></div><!--cardChoice--><div class='cardNumber'><input name='ccn1' id='ccn' type='text' class='long-field' value='" + results[0].maskccn + "' maxlength='19' readonly /></div><div class='cardCVV'><input name='cvv1' id='cvv' type='text' maxlength='5' class='small-field' /></div><div class='creditCardName'><input name='ccname1' id='ccname' type='text' class='long-field' value='" + results[0].ccname + "' readonly/></div><div class='cardDate'><input name='exp11' id='exp1' type='text' maxlength='2' class='small-field' value='" + results[0].ccm + "' readonly /><input name='exp21' id='exp2' type='text' maxlength='4' class='small-field' value='" + results[0].ccy + "' readonly /></div></div><!--creditCard-->").insertAfter("#paymentCardChoice");
                $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice input#' + results[0].cct + '').attr("checked", true);
                $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label').removeClass("active");
                $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label[for="' + results[0].cct + '"]').addClass("active");
                $("li:not(.title,.checkCode)").addClass("checked");
            });
            readytouseCard();
        } else {
            $(".submit-btn").fadeIn();
            $("<div class='creditCardDetails' id='usercurrentccbox'><div class='creditCard'><div class='cardChoice'><span>Choose Card Type</span><input name='cctype1' type='radio' value='V' class='lft-field' id='visa' /><label for='visa'></label><input name='cctype1' type='radio' value='M' class='lft-field' id='mastercard' /><label for='mastercard'></label><input name='cctype1' type='radio' value='A' class='lft-field' id='amex' /><label for='amex'></label></div><!--cardChoice--><div class='cardNumber'><input name='ccn1' id='ccn' type='text' class='long-field' value='" + results[0].maskccn + "' maxlength='19' readonly /></div><div class='cardCVV'><input name='cvv1' id='cvv' type='text' maxlength='5' class='small-field' /></div><div class='creditCardName'><input name='ccname1' id='ccname' type='text' class='long-field' value='" + results[0].ccname + "' readonly/></div><div class='cardDate'><input name='exp11' id='exp1' type='text' maxlength='2' class='small-field' value='" + results[0].ccm + "' readonly /><input name='exp21' id='exp2' type='text' maxlength='4' class='small-field' value='" + results[0].ccy + "' readonly /></div></div><!--creditCard-->").insertAfter("#paymentCardChoice");
            $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice input#' + results[0].cct + '').attr("checked", true);
            $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label').removeClass("active");
            $('#usercurrentccbox .cardChoice label[for="' + results[0].cct + '"]').addClass("active");
            $("li:not(.title,.checkCode)").addClass("checked");
        }
        readytouseCard();
    }, "json");
});
readytouseCard();
```

The function starts and works on the first click but after that it doesn't work again. console log just shows **Window #** and when I click again it show **Window # Window #**

So I was hoping there was a way to kill the function readytouseCard() using .remove();

Thanks in advance

Comment: jquery 'remove' function is used to remove DOM Elements.

Comment: That's a weird way of programming. Why is checklistCheck inside readytouseCard? And, why are you calling readytouseCard more times? What I see it does it just sets a handler for keyup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "remove" functions, you can just override them, e.g. `readytouseCards = function(){}`.

However I don't understand, why you want to to that. And Console logging `Window` is correct, because you have `console.log(this);` on the first line of your function. Since you call `readytouseCards` from global context, `this` is bound to `window`.

**Your actual problem is that you attach an eventhandler inside your** `readytouseCards()`. Thus calling the function the second time attaches the eventhandler **twice**. This results in `checklistCheck()` being called twice on every keyup. This is indicated by your console logging `window` twice.

You need to refactor your whole code:

Attach the eventhandler ONCE in the beginning via `.on()` ([jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) so that elements added to the dom later on have the eventhandler attached too.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.cardCVV input[name=cvv1]', function () { ... }
```

and kill the function `readytouseCard()` by moving the `checklistCheck()` out of it. Finally, omit the `readytouseCard();` calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's global, which means that we can access it through the window.

```
window.readytouseCard() = function(){
  return false;
}
```

Now that we've done that, the functions contents have been replaced with `return false;` which will mimic `nothing happening`.

Answer (score 0):

I have reindented your code. As you can see now, when there are `#usercurrentccbox, #addnewccbox` found after the Ajax request, the function will be called twice. Just remove the first one.

If you want to remove an event listener automatically after it was executed once, jQuery offers [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

You can't delete a function. If the function is determined by an identifier each time it is invoked, you may be able to overwrite that variable with a different function. However, that won't work when the reference to the function is stored in a inaccessible variable, e.g. when added as an event listener. Then you'd need to code:

```
var called = false;
function executeOnlyOnce(...) {
    if (called) return;
    called = true;
    ...
}
```